# SharePoint 2013 CSWP TrimDuplicates:false not working

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, content-search-web-part

I have a content search WebPart on which I have set the property `TrimDupicates` as false and even then I am not getting the duplicate results.

What should be done to get the duplicate results as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please confirm it with the search query tool (codeplex)- there is a checkbox for trim duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll check it and update soon. While editing the webpart, there was no such option. I had to download it and set the `TrimDuplicates` to false under `DataProviderJSON`.

Comment: Thats the only way to do it - I just wanna assert that there is no underlying problem like a typo...